# Kotlin coroutines - delay, how does it work?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am quite used to using RX to handle concurrency, but, in my current job, we have a mix of AsyncTask, Executors + Handlers, Threads and some LiveData thrown in. Now we are thinking about moving towards using Kotlin Coroutines (and in fact have started using it in certain places in the codebase).

Therefore, I need to start wrapping my head around Coroutines, ideally drawing from my existing knowledge of concurrency tools to speed the process up.

I have tried following the Google codelab for them and whilst it's giving me a bit of understanding it's also raising lots of unanswered questions so I've tried getting my hands dirty by writing some code, debugging and looking at log outputs.

As I understand it, a coroutine is composed of 2 main building blocks; suspend functions which are where you do your work and coroutine contexts which is where you execute suspend functions such that you can have a handle on what dispatchers the coroutines will run on.

Here I have some code below, that behaves as I would expect. I have set up a coroutine context using Dispatchers.Main. So, as expected, when I launch the coroutine `getResources` it ends up blocking the UI thread for 5 seconds due to the `Thread.sleep(5000)`:

```
private const val TAG = "Coroutines"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Job() + Dispatchers.Main

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        log("onCreate", "launching coroutine")
        launch {
            val resource = getResource()
            log("onCreate", "resource fetched: $resource")
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).text = resource.toString()
        }
        log("onCreate", "coroutine launched")
    }

    private suspend fun getResource() : Int {
        log("getResource", "about to sleep for 5000ms")
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        log("getResource", "finished fetching resource")
        return 1
    }

    private fun log(methodName: String, toLog: String) {
        Log.d(TAG,"$methodName: $toLog: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I see the following logs:

```
2020-05-28 11:42:44.364 9819-9819/? D/Coroutines: onCreate: launching coroutine: main
2020-05-28 11:42:44.376 9819-9819/? D/Coroutines: onCreate: coroutine launched: main
2020-05-28 11:42:44.469 9819-9819/? D/Coroutines: getResource: about to sleep for 5000ms: main
2020-05-28 11:42:49.471 9819-9819/com.example.coroutines D/Coroutines: getResource: finished fetching resource: main
2020-05-28 11:42:49.472 9819-9819/com.example.coroutines D/Coroutines: onCreate: resource fetched: 1: main
```

As you can see, all the logs originated from the main thread, and there is a 5 second gap between the log before and after the `Thread.sleep(5000)`. During that 5 second gap, the UI thread is blocked, I can confirm this by just looking at the emulator; it doens't render any UI because `onCreate` is blocked.

Now, if I update the `getResources` function to use the suspend fun `delay(5000)` instead of using `Thread.sleep(5000)` like so:

```
private suspend fun getResource() : Int {
    log("getResource", "about to sleep for 5000ms")
    delay(5000)
    log("getResource", "finished fetching resource")
    return 1
}
```

Then what I end up seeing confuses me. I understand `delay` isn't the same as `Thread.sleep`, but because I am running it within the coroutine context which is backed by `Dispatchers.Main`, I expected to see the same result as using `Thread.sleep`.

Instead, what I see is the UI thread is not blocked while the 5 second delay is happening, and the logs look like:

```
2020-05-28 11:54:19.099 10038-10038/com.example.coroutines D/Coroutines: onCreate: launching coroutine: main
2020-05-28 11:54:19.111 10038-10038/com.example.coroutines D/Coroutines: onCreate: coroutine launched: main
2020-05-28 11:54:19.152 10038-10038/com.example.coroutines D/Coroutines: getResource: about to sleep for 5000ms: main
2020-05-28 11:54:24.167 10038-10038/com.example.coroutines D/Coroutines: getResource: finished fetching resource: main
2020-05-28 11:54:24.168 10038-10038/com.example.coroutines D/Coroutines: onCreate: resource fetched: 1: main
```

I can see the UI thread is not blocked in this case as the UI renders whilst the delay is taking place and then the text view is updated after 5 seconds.

So, my question is, how does delay, in this case, not block the UI thread (even though the logs in my suspend function still indicate that the function is running on the main thread...)

Comment: You can think of coroutines like syntactic sugar for writing a series of events through nested callbacks. Calling a suspend function with delay is like telling an executor to do Thread.sleep on a background thread and then running all the code below the delay call in a callback sent to the Main handler after the delay call.

Comment: Yea I'm starting to grok that bit @Tenfour04, but delay is itself a suspend function, and in this case is called in the coroutine context which is backed by Dispatchers.Main and therefore should actually suspend in the main thread right (i.e. should block the main thread)?

Comment: Or does `delay` actually open another coroutine context backed by `Dispatchers.Default`?

Comment: Whenever you call a suspend function, you have no idea without looking at its source code whether it in turn delegates to a different dispatcher or uses some other mechanism to do something in the background before resuming the coroutine’s “continuation”. A properly written suspend function must never block the thread of the dispatcher that called it because it might be the Main dispatcher.

Comment: In an application that works with UI, every suspend function that you write that does blocking actions should wrap those blocking actions in a `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` (or Default) so it is safe to call the function from any coroutine with the confidence that it won’t block the main thread.

Comment: More confused now, I thought the point of a suspend function was that you can write blocking code in there, and it is up to the invoker of the coroutine to determine what coroutine context to run the suspend function in, which in turn determines what dispatcher the suspend function will run in. Am I coming at this from the completely wrong angle?

Comment: So in my example code in the OP, when I have used `override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Job() + Dispatchers.Main`, I was under the impression that the code inside `launch` will run in the main thread (obviously not what I'd want in production code, this is to help me figure out what's going on).

Comment: If your suspend function contains just blocking code, there's no reason for it to be a suspend function. It can just be a blocking, synchrounous function. To write a proper suspend function for something that blocks, you can use withContext: `suspend fun calculateSomething() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { someVeryTimeConsumingBlockingSynchrounousMethod() }` If you want to call blocking code from within a coroutine, you can wrap it in `withContext` or `async`.

Comment: The code in your coroutine with the Main dispatcher is *called* from the main thread, but suspend functions suspend the main thread and can do their long-running actions in the background before resuming the coroutine.

Comment: "and can do their long-running actions in the background" - How do you know if they will or not though?

Comment: "The code in your coroutine with the Main dispatcher is called from the main thread" - So is it the use of Dispatchers.Main that causes the code in the coroutine to be called from the main thread? Or is it that I am calling `launch` from the main thread? For instance, if I change to `Dispatchers.IO`, will the code in the coroutine (i.e. the lambda argument to `launch`) be called from a thread allocated by `Dispatchers.IO`?

Sorry for all the questions, thankyou for answering I appreciate it

Comment: If it's marked `suspend`, you know it will not block the main thread you're calling it from, so long as the author of that `suspend` function didn't make mistakes. There are some compiler warnings for some of the kinds of mistakes you can make while composing a suspend function.

Comment: The coroutine runs with the Dispatcher you give it. In your case above, a bare `launch` call is on the Main Dispatcher of your top-level context, but a `launch(Dispatchers.IO)` call will start it with that new context.

Comment: 1 final question then (sorry); if I change my Dispatcher to `Dispatchers.IO`, in order to invoke the coroutine from a background thread, when my suspend function returns control the coroutine, what thread am I in? Am I back on main thread, or am I back on the thread that `Dispatchers.IO` allocated to run the coroutine in?

Comment: It will return control to the same context it was called from, in that case `IO`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Think of suspend functions as a way to use a function that takes a callback, but doesn't require you to to pass that callback into it. Instead, the callback code is everything under the suspend function call.

This code:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    myTextView.text = "Starting"
    delay(1000L)
    myTextView.text = "Processing"
    delay(2000L)
    myTextView.text = "Done"
}
```

Is somewhat like:

```
myTextView.text = "Starting"
handler.postDelayed(1000L) {
    myTextView.text = "Processing"
    handler.postDelayed(2000L) {
        myTextView.text = "Done"
    }
}
```

Suspend functions should never be expected to block. If they do, they have been composed incorrectly. Any blocking code in a suspend function should be wrapped in something that backgrounds it, like `withContext` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine` (which is lower level because it works directly with the coroutine continuation).

If you try to write a suspend function like this:

```
suspend fun myDelay(length: Long) {
    Thread.sleep(length)
}
```

you will get a compiler warning for "Inappropriate blocking method call". If you push it to a background dispatcher, you won't get the warning:

```
suspend fun myDelay(length: Long) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    Thread.sleep(length)
}
```

If you try to send it to `Dispatchers.Main`, you will get the warning again, because the compiler considers any blocking code on the Main thread to be incorrect.

This should give you and idea of how a suspend function should operate, but keep in mind the compiler cannot always recognize a method call as blocking.

Comment: I'm starting to grok it, thanks so much for your time to help me understand. I digged into the source code of `delay` and found that it ultimately calls into `scheduleResumeAfterDelay` on `HandlerContext` which indeed uses a call to `handler.postDelayed(block, timeMillis)`. So am I right in thinking that threads are being used further down the chain to actually do the delay? I.e. at some point, there is a thread somewhere that is fired up and slept to do the delay? Or is there a lower level mechanism than threads that are being used deep down in the coroutines implementation?

Comment: I haven't dug deep enough to see if Handler's enqueued messages rely on some background thread sleeping, or if Java provides a more direct way to do it. If you suspend your function using `withContext`, Kotlin's dispatchers are managing threads from a thread pool. If you use `suspendCancellableCoroutine`, you are taking control of doing the background stuff however you see fit up until you resume the continuation of the coroutine. `suspendCancellableCoroutine` is often used for converting callback-based code into suspending functions.

Comment: So it looks like `delay` uses a different means of posting the delay, depending on which Dispatcher it's on. Note that the Main dispatcher is defined differently on different platforms. Android's Dispatcher.Main works with Handlers and Loopers to manage its thread pool. There are different Dispatcher.Main implementations for Swing and Javafx.

Comment: I see. I think I've drilled deep enough now to start doing something productive with coroutines. I don't suppose I need to know the nitty gritty implementation details of it to use them, but it does help to have a cursory understanding of how the things work (for me anyway).

Answer (score 3):

The best way to connect your existing intuition with the world of coroutines is to make this mental mapping: whereas in the classical world, the OS schedules threads to CPU cores (preemptively suspending them as needed), a dispatcher schedules coroutines to threads. Coroutines can't be preemptively suspended, this is where the cooperative nature of coroutine concurrency comes in.

With that in mind:

> because I am running it within the coroutine context which is backed by `Dispatchers.Main`, I expected to see the same result as using `Thread.sleep`.

`delay(delayTime)` simply suspends the coroutine and schedules its resumption `delayTime` later. Therefore you should expect to see a very different result than with `Thread.sleep`, which never suspends a coroutine and keeps occupying its thread, a situation comparable to one where `Thread.sleep()` wouldn't allow the CPU core to run other stuff, but would busy-wait.