# How to disable button for 1 sec after clicked in Android?

Tags: android, button, postdelayed

I am using following code for using a button. I works.(sendBtn is a button in a fragment)

```
sendText = view.findViewById(R.id.send_text);
    View sendBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.send_btn);
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> send(sendText.getText().toString()));
```

Now i want to disable the button for 1 sec after a click

I found following solution **but above code works** *"**without** onClick(View v)*"method and **without implementing** View.OnClickListener in class. **How to provide delay in such case.**.How code is working without onClick method.

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.click)).setEnabled(false);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ((Button) findViewById(R.id.click))
                    .setEnabled(true);

            }
        }, 1000);

    }
});
```

Comment: did you check following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064123/kotlin-coroutines-delay-how-does-it-work

Comment: What you need is some kind of SingleClickListener with an subsequent click interval . [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608720/android-preventing-double-click-on-a-button).

Answer (score 1):

Use this method when you want to interrupt user clicks:

```
private static long mLastClickTime = 0L;

public static boolean isOpenRecently() {
    if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) {
        return true;
    }
    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.sendBtn) {
        if (isOpenRecently()) return;
        // Your logic
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are using lambda in your code, where `v->{}` represents the `onCLick(View v)` function.

```
sendBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> send(sendText.getText().toString()));
```

You can do the following to disable the button for 1 second

```
 void doOnSendButtonClick(View v){
    //Send the message (your logic here)
    send(sendText.getText().toString());

    //Disable button
    sendBtn.setEnabled(false);

    //enable button after 1000 millisecond
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
        sendBtn.setEnabled(true);
    }, 1000);
}
```

And call this method when user clicks on the button

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener(view -> doOnSendButtonClick(view));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer).

```
CountDownTimewr timer = new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        // enable button
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.click)).setEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        // disable btn and start timer of one second in millis
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.click)).setEnabled(false);
        timer.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way

- Handler(Looper.getmainLooper()) and remove callback after you done your task inside runnable thread...also try to put this logic in any method outside in this class and call from setonclicklistener
- Try the Timer.shedule with timertask
- you can use runOnUIThread method inside where you can update UI.
- you can also try to check the time difference of click and enable again in looping like while.