# How can i show multiple text one by one in one activity android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, function, android-studio

how can i set Text for while time and when one text will finished then automatically i want to show another text in one activity!
Can i do it in android studio ?
if yes then how ?

Show text for 3/4 second then another text will show there in one activity

Comment: Do you have some example of code that isn't working for you?

Answer (score 0):

call this inside onCreate function. we are using coroutine here. follow this link for more reference -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/62065829/8879652

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
            myText.text = "text 1"
            delay(3000L)
            myText.text = "text 2"
            delay(4000L)
            myText.text = "text 3"
        }
```